# get sheet data without the hidden columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am currently working on GAS project, for the moment I have a table in a sheet and the idea is that my collaborators will be able to choose the format of the table, which column and which row they want to save. I thought about using the hiding column and row features but is it possible in my apps script to get only the data which they chose to save and not the hidden data ? Thank you for you answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Apps Script works analogously to the Sheets UI

**Explanation**

If from the user interface you select the desired data by "click&drag", the hidden columns located between the start and the end column will be also selected (and copied). Instead you need to select the data of interest manually with "Ctrl" and click, see [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4604028?hl=en).

**How to transfer this to Apps Script?**

Apps Script features the method [sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(columnPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#iscolumnhiddenbyusercolumnposition) (and `isRowHiddenByUser`, `isRowHiddenByFilter` etc.).  You can use it to select only the ranges / the values of a datarange in columns and rows that are not hidden.

This implies the implementation of loops and conditions statements, so is not necessary an elegant solution.

Comment: The method you give me is exaclty what I'm looking for, I had searched in the doc but I didn't find it. I can use loops and conditions, it's not a problem for me. Thank for your help.